# R: Create a stacked area plot of time series in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, charts, stacked-area-chart

I have a data frame that is a percentage allocation for each variable. There are four variables where the sum of the rows are equal to 1. Here is a example output of the data frame:

```
dates       A   B   C   D
1997-01-01  0.2 0.2 0.5 0.1 
1997-02-01  0.3 0.2 0.4 0.1
1997-03-01  0.1 0.3 0.2 0.4
...         ... ... ... ...
2017-12-01  0.2 0.2 0.1 0.5
```

How can I create a similar stacked area plot like where the x-axis shows the years, and y-axis is from 0 to 1 (from https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_density.html):

[image]

My attempt at following the instructions produced this, which is not exactly what I am looking for:

[image]

I get the error message:

> Error: A:D must evaluate to column positions or names, not a double vector
>
> In addition: Warning messages:
>
> 1: In x:y : numerical expression has 252 elements: only the first used
>
> 2: In x:y : numerical expression has 252 elements: only the first used

Comment: what code did you use to produce the shown plot?

Comment: I used `ggplot(df, aes(x = dates, y = values)) + geom_area(position = "fill")`

Comment: There's no `values` column in your dataframe.

Comment: My data frame looks like this `df <- data.frame(dates = dates, value = cbind(A, B, C, D))`.

Comment: That's not what you have in your post. See my answer below.

Comment: Please [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on making an R post that's easy to answer. That includes a representative sample of your data, code you've written so far, and any error messages we should know about, *posted in the question*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you want area, not density. Also you want to reshape your data to a long format.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- read.table(text = "
dates       A   B   C   D
1997-01-01  0.2 0.2 0.5 0.1 
1997-02-01  0.3 0.2 0.4 0.1
1997-03-01  0.1 0.3 0.2 0.4
", header = TRUE)

df %>% 
  mutate(dates = as.Date(dates)) %>% 
  gather(variable, value, A:D) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = dates, y = value, fill = variable)) +
  geom_area()
```

[image]

Comment: I only get error messages when I try your code. My `df` is also a data frame and structured like yours.

Comment: In that case the error is very clear. Your dataframe does not contain the columns `A` to `D`.

Comment: That is weird. Because I have four columns A, B, C and D. And I have also tried to give names through `colnames()`. `dim` also gives 5 in cols.

Comment: I resolved the issue. However, do you know how to add black lines to each variable, i.e. black lines at the edges?

Comment: `geom_area(color = "black")`